# dateutil.parser.parse() and lost timezone information

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, datetime, python-dateutil

I am trying to `dateutil.parser.parse()` to parse the default `str(datetime.datetime.now())` output using timezone-aware datetimes. However, `parse()` seems to lose the timezone information and replace it with the local time timezone. Below is the IPython output:

```
In [1]: from django.utils.timezone import now
In [3]: import dateutil
In [4]: t = now()
In [6]: print t
2014-07-14 08:51:49.123342+00:00

In [7]: st = unicode(t)
In [8]: print dateutil.parser.parse(st)
2014-07-14 08:51:49.123342+02:00
```

As far I understood `dateutil` does some heurestics when guessing the date format and it might go wrong here.

- How to give exact datetime format for parsing timezone-aware datetimes?
- Even better - if the format is known how to parse this datetime using only Python stdlib, without dateutil dependency?

Comment: I am aware of `USE_TZ` - however this question is about parsing dates and `dateutil` behavior, not about Django.

Comment: Then why are you using `django.util.timezone`?

Comment: I wanted to generate a datetime with timezone. That is kind of the easiest way. I think I was quite specific what I was asking - please tell me if there is anything in the question what can be improved.

Comment: The premise of your question is wrong - `datetime.datetime.now()` does not give you a timezone aware object; so when you do `str(datetime.datetime.now())`, there is no timezone information in the string. Is your question basically _"How to parse a string that represents a date and time with a timezone offset into a datetime object"_?

Comment: Np. It happens to everyone :)

Comment: Actually I think it might be a bug regarding +00:00 handling.

Answer (score -3):

`timezone.now` [will give you an aware datetime object if `USE_TZ` is true](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.timezone). You don't need to parse it further.

In this example, USE_TZ is True, and the timezone is set to UTC:

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone as djtz
>>> i = djtz.now()
>>> type(i)
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
>>> i.tzinfo
<UTC>
```

As far as dateutil goes, it will parse your string correctly:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> s = '2014-07-14 08:51:49.123342+00:00'
>>> parse(s).tzinfo
tzutc()
>>> z = parse(s)
>>> z
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 14, 8, 51, 49, 123342, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

You can see its picking up the correct timezone (UTC in this case).

The [default format specifiers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) only accept +0000 as the offset format with `%z`, or the three letter timezone name with `%Z`; but you cannot use this to *parse*, only to *format*:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2014-07-14 08:51:49.123342+0000', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 317, in _strptime
    (bad_directive, format))
ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z'
>>> datetime.datetime.strftime(z, '%Z')
'UTC'
>>> datetime.datetime.strftime(z, '%z')
'+0000'
```

Comment: Please see my comment - this question is not about Django and this answer is totally unrelated to the question.